# How to remove lines in txt file with less than current date in php

Tags: php

I want to remove the line from a text file that less than the current date...Only remove the line that End date is less than the current date...

F: 6038230918 6038230918 #End-date = 2021-04-19

F: 3846731393 3846731393  #End-date = 2021-04-18

F: 647794887 647794887   #End-date = 2021-04-30

```
    $fname = "test.txt";
    $lines = file($fname, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    foreach($lines as $line) if(strpos($line, $date) !== false) $out .= $line; 
    $f = fopen($fname, "w");  
    fwrite($f, $out);  
    fclose($f);
```

Comment: My problem is that lines are not removing  with the less dates

Comment: Of course they aren't, the code you've provided makes no attempt to do that. You're only checking if the line contains the date or not. You'll need to research how to compare dates, and also extract the date from the line to do the comparison.

Comment: i research it... but didnt get any solution thats why i post this answere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), parse out the date and compare the value.

```
<?php
$lines = [
 'F: 6038230918 6038230918 #End-date = 2021-04-19',
 'F: 3846731393 3846731393 #End-date = 2021-04-18',
 'F: 647794887 647794887 #End-date = 2021-04-30'
];

$filtered = array_filter($lines, fn($v) => time() < strtotime(explode('#End-date = ', $v)[1]));

print_r(implode(PHP_EOL, $filtered));
```

Result:

`F: 647794887 647794887 #End-date = 2021-04-30`

https://3v4l.org/AgMGp

Comment: $lines = file($filepath, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);$filtered = array_filter($lines, fn($v) => time() < strtotime(explode('#End-date = ', $v)[1]));
    
    $data1=implode("\n", array_values($filtered));
    file_put_contents("$filepath", $data1);